# How could I detect USB insertion without polling using Ruby and WMI?

Tags: ruby, windows-xp, wmi

I read the following article: [Using Ruby & WMI to Detect a USB Drive](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/06/using-ruby-wmi-to-detect-usb-drive.html)

However, this method would require me to keep polling inside a loop. Is it possible to register and have my script be notified when USB is inserted/ejected ?

I am looking for a Windows XP solution.

Answer (score 2):

I can't help you much with Ruby, but WMI also supports monitored events. There exists an extrinsic event called [Win32_DeviceChangeEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here is a simple PowerShell code to use it:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM   Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType=2"
Register-WMIEvent -Query $query -Action { Write-Host "A device has been inserted"}
```

The code given into Action parameter is called each time a device is inserted. I don't know to handle such a query in Ruby.

Comment: Yes, Tempus listed "Using Ruby & WMI to Detect a USB Drive" in their comment.