# Batch sript for running a file when a usb is plugged

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there any batch script which can be used to run a file kept in your system(eg: C:\Program Files\abc.exe) when a pendrive is pluged in.

What i am thinking is this batch script when executed will add or modify some registry keys thus enabling the file in the system (this case: C:\Program Files\abc.exe) to run when a pendrive is inserted

Comment: A simple way would be have it run every x seconds/minutes, save the list of drive letters to a file, and see if the amount of drive letters change between calls. Though there may be a more direct approach, possibly making use of a .vbs file

Comment: I assume you disabled `autorun`?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a batch solution, but WMI has functionality built in that you can use for this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16374535/1324345) to a similar question.

In your case, the code would be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2"
Register-WMIEvent -Query $query -Action { invoke-item "C:\Program Files\abc.exe"}
```

If you need to look for (or filter out) specific pendrives, more work would be involved.

Comment: I am new to wmi ,i saved the above script as wmi.vbs and tried to open it but its showing following error "Line:1 ; Char:1 ; Error:invalid Character ; Code: 800A0408 ; Source: Microsoft VB..."

Comment: Because it's not VBScript, it's PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to SmokeyPHP's answer that you could put an identifying file on the pendrive. Something with a unique name. Your script that runs on a schedule could enumerate the available drives and look for that file name. It doesn't seem super efficient, but I don't know of a trigger for USB things being added.